# How do I use Vue.component with modules or Vue CLI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I'm stuck on how to declare Vue.component inside export default

this is from the tutorial by [vuejs.org](https://vuejs.org)

[image]

instead of using `var app = new vue`, I use

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  
  el: "#app-7",
  data() {
    return {
      barangBelanjaan: [
        { id: 0, barang: 'Sayuran' },
        { id: 1, barang: 'Keju' },
        { id: 2, barang: 'Makanan yang lain' }
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

and i dont know where to write Vue.component in export default app

thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components can be registered globally or locally.  `Vue.component` is the way to register globally, which means all other components can then use this component in their templates.

#### Global components

When using a build tool like Vue CLI, do this in *main.js*:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import todoItem from '@/components/todoItem.vue'  // importing the module

Vue.component('todoItem', todoItem);              // ✅ Global component
```

-or-

#### Local components

Or you can register a component in a specific component using the `components` option.

```js
components: {
  todoItem
}
```

So your *App.vue* would become:

```js
import todoItem from '@/components/todoItem.vue'  // importing the module

export default {
  name: "App",
  el: "#app-7",
  components: {      // ✅ Local components
    todoItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
      barangBelanjaan: [
        { id: 0, barang: 'Sayuran' },
        { id: 1, barang: 'Keju' },
        { id: 2, barang: 'Makanan yang lain' }
      ],
    };
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Various recording options are possible, for example

```
components: {      
    todoItem:() => import("@/components/todoItem.vue")
}
```

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  el: "#app-7",
  components: {      
    todoItem:() => import("@/components/todoItem.vue")
  },
  data() {
    return {
      barangBelanjaan: [
        { id: 0, barang: 'Sayuran' },
        { id: 1, barang: 'Keju' },
        { id: 2, barang: 'Makanan yang lain' }
      ],
    };
  },
}
```